# Get browser name using JavaScript single function

Tags: javascript

Is there any function like `$(window).width()` that can show the browser name as output?

I search a lot but unable to find this type of function for browser name.

Comment: There's no built-in JavaScript function, no.

Comment: You could use : http://jquery.thewikies.com/browser/

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_navigator.asp Isn't this built-in Javascript?

Comment: @Seanny123 - `window.navigator` _is_ built in, yes, but it doesn't actually provide a property that gives you the browser's name. (You would think that the `navigator.appName` property would, but it doesn't.)

Answer (score 2):

I didn't test it in each browser but this code should work:

```
var browser = navigator.userAgent;
    browser = browser.split("/");
    browser = browser[2];
    browser = browser.split(" ");
    browser = browser[browser.length-1];

alert(browser);
```

Here the link is : http://jsfiddle.net/3erQJ/